# How to make my window cover all the open windows system wide?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm developing a WPF application(scheduler), that would announce the start of some events. For that, I need to show my window and make it cover all other windows in the system, which do not belong to my application. Is it possible in WPF application?

Comment: What you means by 'cover'?

Comment: Please, share your code and what have you tried so far

Comment: Please more details

Comment: @picolino Bring it to the front

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set some windows properties :

```
           WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
           WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
```

In this case, you will not have borders and it will take all the screen.

If you want it to be on the top of other windows, tou can set the TopMost property = true;

```
  Topmost = true;
```